# EmEditorで可能な使用言語について

Tags: emeditor

お世話になっております。
EmEditorはJavaScript、Rubyなどは可能というのはマニュアルで見ました。
R言語、Common Lispとの連携は可能でしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ここ [LIBRARY DOWNLOAD](https://www.emeditor.com/library/) にある`Syntax Files`というのがそうだとすると、[R](https://www.emeditor.com/files/r-esy/) は有るようですが、Lispは無さそうです。[newLISP](https://www.emeditor.com/files/newlisp-esy/) というLISP風スクリプト言語のが有るようなので、それを参考に自分で作るとか？ [新しい構文ファイルを作成するには](http://www.emeditor.org/ja/howto_customize_syntax_file.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご質問は、マクロとして使用できる言語のことを指しているのだと思います。そうだとすると、EmEditor のマクロでは、`JavaScript` と `VBScript` 以外にも、任意の `ActiveScript` を利用できます。しかし、`R言語`、`Common Lisp` が `ActiveScript` に対応しているのは聞いたことがありません。[Active Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Scripting) に、使用できる言語の一部の一覧が書かれていますのでご参考になさってください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Active Scriptingに書かれている言語との互換性と理解致しました。

Answer (score 0):

言語のハイライトを指しているのであれば、メニューを見る限り R や Common Lisp はプリセットの設定としてはおそらく用意されていません。

ただし自分で定義を設定すれば独自にハイライトさせることは可能なようです。

**参考ヘルプ:**

[EmEditor 使い方: 新しい設定を定義するには](http://www.emeditor.org/ja/howto_customize_config_new.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。